# Как выбрать конкретное значение css через Js (Без jquery)

Tags: javascript, css

Хочу сделать блок прозрачным при нажатии на кнопку, установил фоновый рисунок и цвет фона. Как получить в js канал прозрачности и фоновую картинку, чтобы их потом изменить?

```
#block {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-image: url(img/bg-grid.png);
}
```

Comment: Вот тут хороший ответ на англ, но смысл там понятен - приведен скрипт на js для кросс-браузерного решения. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById('block').style.backgroundColor` вернет строку вида `"rgb(255, 255, 255)"` или `"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)"` взависимости от того установлена ли прозрачность в 1 или нет. Соответственно нужно проверять получаемое заначение, например так:

```
var bkgColor = document.getElementById('block').style.backgroundColor;
var match = bkgColor.match(/^rgba\([\d.]+, [\d.]+, [\d.]+, ([\d.]+)/);
var alphaChannel = 1; // значение по умолчанию
if (null !== match) // есть альфа канал
    alphaChannel = match[1];
```

`document.getElementById('block').style.backgroundImage` для background-image